# Map json field from child object

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, gson

Here is the description of issue to convert Json string to json.

```
Address{
    private long id;
    private String city;
}

Employee{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}
```

Client will send a request with JSON of employee

```
{"id": 1, "name": "ABC", "address": {"id": 1, "city": "XYZ"}}
```

Now i want to convert the input json into below format where addressId = id field of Address class.

```
Output{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long addressId; 
}
```

is there any way to achieve this.
I have tried Jackson and Gson also.

Comment: Why not JSON.Parse the whole object then selecting the child

Comment: I guess the best way to achieve is to write a custom Jackson deserializer

Answer (score 2):

With Jackson, you can add a `class AddressId` to wrap the address with just the `id` field and an annotated constructor that takes an `AddressId` as argument. Add getters and other constructors as needed. This doesn't require defining `Employee` and `Address` classes only `Output`.

```
class Output {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long addressId;

    @JsonCreator
    public Output(
            @JsonProperty("id") long id,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("address") AddressId address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.addressId = address.getId();
    }
}

class AddressId {
    private long id;
}
```

In this case, you would also need to configure your `ObjectMapper` to quietly ignore unknown JSON fields:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Another alternative, that doesn't require `class AddressId`, would be to create a custom setter for the `addressId` field based on the `Map<String, Object>` that Jackson uses internally when deserializing. This is how `Output` would look like in this case (add other setters/getters you may need):

```
class Output {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("address")
    public void setAddressId(final Map<String, Object> address) {
        addressId = (Integer) address.get("id");
    }

    private long addressId;
}
```

Comment: I don't  want to create separate class  "AddressId"

Comment: No, class Address  is not there at receiving side

Comment: I am afraid you will have to write some code somewhere to map the `id` from `address` to the `addressId` field. No library can do that by itself. I'll another alternative that doesn't require defining a class.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Gson api to convert object from json.

Similar to the below code. Not sure whether it has no syntax error. But, this is possible.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Employee emp = gson.fromJson("{"id": 1, "name": "ABC", "address": {"id": 1, "city": "XYZ"}}", 
    Employee.class);
```

If the above code doesn't work out, try using `dozer`

Comment: I want to convert given json into form of Output class.

Comment: What do you mean by form of Output class? You can get the Employee object after the conversion. Use it where you want...